# How to call an onClick function of a child component being stored inside of a variable

Tags: reactjs

I am trying to send a function which is declared in the parent component as a prop to the child component. Upon clicking a certain icon in the child component it should trigger the function in the parent component. But the thing is in the parent side of the code I am storing the child comp in a variable and when I try clicking the icon afterwards it tells me that no such function exists.

This is the child component

```
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.delete = this.delete.bind(this);
    }

    delete() {
        this.props.OndeleteLayer('Hexa')
    }

    render() {

            return (

                <div class="shadow-sm p-3 mb-5 bg-white rounded" style={Box}>

                    Hexagon Layer
                     <FaTrashAlt style={{ color: 'black', marginLeft: 50 }} onClick={this.delete} />     
                    <div class="rounded" style={strip} />


                </div>
            )




    }
```

this is the part where I  try to store it in a variable in the parent side, and more code of the parent side...

```
  render() {

        const A = new function () {
            return (<HexaButon OndeleteLayer={this.deleteLayer} />
 )  }

        return (

            <div class="rounded" style={leftBox}>


                {A}

                <ul>
                    {this.state.UILayers.map(item => (

                        <li key={item}> {item} </li>
                    )
                    )

                    }
                </ul>

                <Button onClick={this.toggle} style={{ color: "White", fontSize: 10 }} color="warning"> + Add Layer </Button>

                <Modal centered={true} size={'lg'} isOpen={this.state.modal} toggle={this.state.toggle} className={this.props.className}>
                    <ModalBody>
                    <Nav style={{ color: "Black", fontSize: 12 }} tabs>
                            <NavItem>
                                <NavLink className={classnames({ active: this.state.activeTab === '1' })} onClick={() => { this.toggleTab('1'); }}>
                                    Create New Layer
                                </NavLink>
                            </NavItem>
                            <NavItem>
                                <NavLink className={classnames({ active: this.state.activeTab === '2' })} onClick={() => { this.toggleTab('2'); }} >
                                    Created Data Layers
                                </NavLink>
                            </NavItem>
                    </Nav>

                    <TabContent activeTab={this.state.activeTab}>
                        <TabPane tabId="1">
                                <hr />
                                <br />
                                <h1 style={{ fontSize: 15, fontWeight: "bold" }}> CREATE NEW LAYERS </h1>

                            <DropDown onGetValue={this.getValue} hexaActivate={this.hexaActivate} arcActivate={this.arcActivate} />
                            <div style={{ color: "black" }}>
                                    <br/>
                                    <h1 style={{ fontSize: 12, fontWeight: "bold" }}>  {this.state.LayerValue} </h1>

                                    {this.displayInput()}


                                    <Button type="button" color="warning" onClick={this.handleAddData} size="sm" disabled={this.state.LayerValue == ''}  > Add </Button >
                                    <Button type="button" color="warning" onClick={this.Submit} size="sm" > Submit </Button >

                            </div>
                                <hr />

                                </TabPane>
                        </TabContent>

                        <TabContent activeTab={this.state.activeTab}>
                            <TabPane tabId="2">
                                <div style={{ color: "black" }}>
                                    <hr/> <br/>

                                    <h1 style={{ fontSize: 15, fontWeight: "bold" }}> CREATED DATA LAYERS </h1>

                                    <Button onClick={this.presetHexagon} size="sm" outline color="warning">
                                    <Card style={{ width: 200 }}>
                                        <CardBody>
                                            <Media style={{ marginTop: -10, marginLeft: 10 }} object src="Layer Icon 1.png" alt=" Hexagon Sample Layer" />
                                            <CardText style={{ textAlign: "center", marginTop:10, fontWeight: 'bold', fontSize: 10 }} > SAMPLE HEXAGON LAYER </CardText>
                                            </CardBody>
                                            </Card>
                                    </Button>



                               </div>
                                <hr/>

                            </TabPane>
                        </TabContent>
                        <Button onClick={this.toggle} style={{ color: "White", fontSize: 10 }} color="warning"> Close </Button>

                    </ModalBody>
                </Modal>

                </div>

            )

    }
```

and this is the actual delete function in the parent component, I've already bind this in the constructor

```
constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.arcActivate = this.arcActivate.bind(this);
        this.hexaActivate = this.hexaActivate.bind(this);
        this.getValue = this.getValue.bind(this);
        this.toggleTab = this.toggleTab.bind(this);
        this.Submit = this.Submit.bind(this);
        this.toggle = this.toggle.bind(this);
        this.presetHexagon = this.presetHexagon.bind(this);
        this.deleteLayer = this.deleteLayer.bind(this);

        this.state = {



            arcData: [{
                srcLongitude: 0,
                srcLatiitude: 0,
                trgtLongitude: 0,
                trgtLatitude: 0
            }],

            srcLongitude: 0,
            srcLatitude: 0,
            trgtLongitude: 0,
            trgtLatitude: 0,


            data: [{
                Longitude: 0,
                Latitude: 0,
                count : 0}],

            Longitude: 0,
            Latitude: 0,
            count: 0,
            activeTab: '1',

            modal: false,
            Arc: false,
            Hexa: false,

            LayerValue: '',
            UILayers : [],
            DATA_HEXA: [[103.84215184, 1.2700346],

            ],
            DATA_ARC: [{ sourcePosition: [-122.269029, 37.80787], targetPosition: [-122.271604, 37.803664] },
            { sourcePosition: [-122.269029, 37.80787], targetPosition: [-122.274604, 37.803664] }]
        };
    }

    deleteLayer(type) {


       console.log('delete activated')

    }
```

upon pressing the icon in the child component should activate the function in the parent component but it won't do that if I store it in a variable like i. I did...it throws an error stating that no such function exists when it clearly does

Comment: can you show more code of parent component?

Comment: I dont think the rest of the code is relevant but sure if you want.

Comment: Replace `{A}` with `<HexaButon OndeleteLayer={this.deleteLayer} />`. You do not need to call function. It should work.

Comment: Yes but.. i dont want to do that.. i want to store it inside of a variable... 
basically what i am trying to do is to have multiple variables like these and having them stored inside of an array then being displayed as a list... 

Is there anyway i can execute the ondeleteLayer by storing the component in a variable?

Comment: The problem is `this` is undefined in function call(which is being created). You can try changing the function to arrow function. `const A = () => <HexaButon OndeleteLayer={this.deleteLayer} />;`.  It should work.

Comment: Now it fails to show the component which is to be rendered

Comment: you need to call using `{A()}`.

Comment: It worked... Thanks a bunch :)

Comment: As you are not passing any argument to the function. You can replace `const A = () => <HexaButon OndeleteLayer={this.deleteLayer} />;' with `const A = <HexaButon OndeleteLayer={this.deleteLayer} />;` and `{A()}` with `{A}`.